# How to bypass Captive Portal issue in iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, macos

I have a Wi-Fi router within which a Web page is hosted. When I go to Settings in iPhone and select the this particular Wi-Fi network, this web page is popped up (the web page present within the Wi-Fi router). I found that this phenomenon is called Captive portal.

Please suggest me a way to bypass this Authentication process using this Webpage. And do it from with in the Wi-Fi screen of the Settings app. Do I need to make any changes to the Webpage hosted within the Wi-Fi router.

Answer (score 0):

In the Wi-Fi router you might try to "whitelist" your device by IP (DHCP reservation) or by MAC address, to not include the captive portal restriction.

You might try modifying the webpage to recognize your device IP or MAC, and proceed to whatever marks the device "authorized" on the network (usually done by clicking Agree or entering a passcode on the webpage, whatever everyone else presented with the captive portal page is required to do)

iPhone/iPad specifically requires access to apple.com/library/test/success.html to "test" if the device is behind a captive portal or not, if it can't reach that page, with the expected content, then it must be behind the captive portal and therefore show the webpage right after associating to the wireless.  Other devices use their own URL, Windows Phones/laptops will use msftncsi.com for example.

Some Apple device users have reported their device thinks it's trapped behind a captive portal, even though the network does not implement a captive portal - this is because Apple has many problems keeping their own URL up.  There are have also been many "bugs" in their captive portal detection since iOS6, see: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4317971?start=0&tstart=0